# KS 2 samples test and the amount of data

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am testing two distributions using KS 2 samples test (from Scipy). I plot the columns where the `statistics` value is greater than 0.025 (since when I examine by hand most of the columns have below 0.025). However I come up with this plot:

[image: Distribution plot]

Each row plots the distribution in the `train` and `test` dataset. As you can see, they are nearly the same. So my question is: does the amount of data affect the test? Because in the `train` I have ~23k `rows` but in test I only have ~3k rows.

Comment: Do you mean the amount of data or the fact that your sample sizes aren’t balanced?

Comment: The amount of data is not balance (23k vs 3k), so I wonder if that can be the case the statistics value is high.

Comment: What statistics value is high?

Comment: In R K-S test has a rather modest limit on sample sizes. I suspect this is to prevent small inevitable quirks in sampling from leading to rejection that is 'statistically valid', but unwarranted on practical grounds.

Comment: @Dave it only returns two values: `statistic` and `pvalue`. I guess the `statistic` is the D. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html